# REST API call with Ember js

Tags: javascript, rest, tomcat, ember.js, ember-data

How to use any rest api(json) in Ember templates(hbs). I have a service deployed on apache tomcat and I want to use its response in ember js. I tried all the things available online but no luck.

Below is my code snippets;

```
-----------app\adaptors\application.js--------------------
    import DS from 'ember-data';
    import Ember from 'ember';

    var App = window.App = Ember.Application.extend();

    App.UserAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
      find: function(){
          return Ember.$.getJSON('http://localhost:8082/emberTestService');
        }
    });
--------------routes\user.js----------------------
    import Ember from 'ember';

    var App = window.App = Ember.Application.extend();

    App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

      model: function(){
        var adapter = App.UserAdapter.create();
        return adapter.find();
      }
    });
-------------templates\application.hbs---------------
    <h1>Welcome in app</h1>
    {{log 'Name is:' name}}
    {{name}}
```

Service http://localhost:8082/emberTestService returns {
  "name": "Tomcat"
}
and I want this response to return on my template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by changing the json response type from service end. Service http://localhost:8082/emberTestService returns { "name": "Tomcat" } but ember requires [{ "name": "Tomcat" }]

I used `String userResponseListValue = "[ " + gson.toJson(listMap) + " ]";` to make the json response mentioned above.